# How to change backround paragraph in richtextbox control (c#)?

Tags: c#, richtextbox

I have rich text box and i save it's content to RTF file.
However, i'm trying to set background color to the paragraph, but the richTextBox.Backgroung doesn't work, i also try to use the selectedText property - but it's colorize only the the text...
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

if you select the paragraph you want to change the background for you should be able to use `richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.Blue;`.

Comment: i tryied it, but it colorize only the text lines (like highlited text), not all the paragraph

Comment: Hi, I probably missunderstood a little. Are you using WPF? Have you seen the examples on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.aspx ? The Paragraph element should accept Brushes when setting the Background property.